# Automatically redirect PPA to new package name

Tags: launchpad

I maintain the PPA for Bookworm here:
https://launchpad.net/bookworm

Recently I have changed the package name from "bookworm" to "com.github.babluboy.bookworm" based on the RDNN requirements of Elementary OS AppStore

This requires that the installation on Ubuntu is done by the command "sudo apt-get install com.github.babluboy.bookworm" instead of "sudo apt-get install bookworm".

While I have signposted this on Launchpad and the Bookworm website, there are a lots of posts and blogs on the internet from earlier asking users to use the "sudo apt-get install bookworm" command. This will install an old package (still in the PPA) which I don't update anymore.

Is there a way I can set up in Launchpad so that the older package automatically points to the new one for installation.

A hack that I can think of is to update the old package so that there is a big banner on the app providing instructions to switch to the new package. But thought of asking here if there is a more elegant way to manage package name changes in PPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a transitional package with the old name. This will be an empty package with no actual contents, which has the new package as a dependency. When people update/install the `bookworm` package, it will be installed, and will pull the new package as a dependency. A future version of the new package can declare the old one as a conflict, and remove it while updating.

Debian Wiki has the information you need in much more detail. For a number of package transition scenarios, see this:

https://wiki.debian.org/PackageTransition

`Case #5 : Rename` is what you need from there. The exact page you want is this

https://wiki.debian.org/RenamingPackages

There are other methods explained on that page, like the 'Clean Slate Method', but the 'Transition package method' is the one which is much more cleaner, and recommended. (If you search apt for 'transitional package', you'll find a lot of them).

Comment: Need some help in implementing the above. Did the following: (1) removed all the code from launchpad (2) left a debian folder with the control file updated as per the suggested transition page. However it is failing with the error: dpkg-source: error: bookworm-0.6/debian/control doesn't list any binary package

Comment: The receipe for the dummy package is here: https://code.launchpad.net/~bablu-boy/+recipe/bookworm-transition

Comment: @SiddharthaDas You will need to make a couple of changes in there

1. Add an empty line between the `Source` and `Package` line in the control file.
2. Add a Maintainer field in the control file
3. Change the name of the package in the changelog file

Comment: Adding to that, the format of the control file, and the requirement of two paragraphs, is described here https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#document-ch-controlfields

Comment: Many thanks for the pointer. The package built fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help. :)